# How to set a property as an array i initial state?

Tags: immutable.js

In my reducer I set initial state by:

```
const initialState = fromJS({
  results: [],
});
```

However if I try to print **results** by

> initialState.get('results')

I get an **immutable Map**.

On the other hand if in my reducer (listening to an action) I set the array via

```
...
case LOAD_SUCCESS:
  return state
     .set('results', []);
...
```

the array will be an **actual (non-Immutable) array** after executing:

> state.get('results')

(e.g. in a selector defined via **reselect**)

**Why?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `fromJS` docs:

> Deeply converts plain JS objects and arrays to Immutable Maps and Lists.

That said, `fromJS({ results: [] })` is equal to `Map({ results: List([])})`

as soon as you call `state.set('results', [])`, you replace `List([])` with plain array `[]`.

This is a classical trap for new starters.

The way I see it is you have to choose to either always use List there, or plain array.

**List way**:

Initialize: `const state = fromJS({results: []})`

Reduce: `return state.update("results", list => list.clear())`

**Array way #1**:

Initialize: `const state = fromJS({results: null})`

INIT reduce (dispatched once, to init state) `return state.set("results", [])`

Reduce: `return state.set("results", [1, 2, 3])`

**Array way #2**:

Initialize: `const state = Map({results: []})`

Reduce: `return state.set("results", [1, 2, 3])`

---

I'd recommend to always use **Array way #2**. It adds more code, as you have to control `List` / `Map` for each state's field, but it guarantees you that you get exactly what you want.

In the end it comes something like this:

`const initialState = Map({
   results: [],
   some_field_as_list: List([]),
   some_field_as_map: Map([]),
   ... // etc
});`

Answer (score 0):

`fromJS({ results: [] })` is equal to `Map({ results: List([])})`,

Using `state.set('results', [])` you replace `List([])` with plain `[]`

I found this helpful in this case:

- Initialize: `const state = fromJS({results: []})`
- **Reduce: `return state.set('results', List([1,2,3]));`**

It was better than using plain array because later you can use `setIn` function editing the same `state` variable:

- `return state.setIn(['results',state.get("results").size], nextElement);`

or

- `return state.setIn(['results',-1], lastElement);`