# What is the proper way of updating this Redux store state in React app

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I have a React app which uses Redux for state management. The initial structure of the store is as follows:

```
const initialState = fromJS({
  visitorRecords: [],
  approvedBookingId: null,
});
```

At some point my **visitorRecords** becomes something similar to this:

```
[  
   Map {  
      "id":"1556008644569",
      "expectedArrival":"Thu, 25 Apr 2019 08:31:00 GMT",
      "lastName":"Vath",
      "notes":"",
      "actualDeparture":"",
      "actualArrival":"",
      "visitor":"Sven Vath",
      "status":2,
      "cardNumber":2,
      "employeeBeingVisited":"John Doe",
      "firstName":"Sven",
      "expectedDeparture":"Fri, 26 Apr 2019 08:31:00 GMT",
      "verbalStatus":"Visitor returned pass",
      "company":"Disney"
   },
   Map {  
      "id":"1555586876781",
      "expectedArrival":"Thu, 18 Apr 2019 06:30:00 GMT",
      "lastName":"A.",
      "notes":"",
      "actualDeparture":"",
      "actualArrival":"",
      "visitor":"Christoph.",
      "status":0,
      "cardNumber":1,
      "employeeBeingVisited":"Jean Pier",
      "firstName":"Pablo",
      "expectedDeparture":"Sat, 20 Apr 2019 15:30:00 GMT",
      "verbalStatus":"Waiting for visitor arrival",
      "company":"Disney"
   }
]
```

What I want to do in my reducer is to update a specific record by its id. I have the id and the values for the edit fields coming from my action but I don't know how to handle them following the best practices for update.

This is what my reducer looks like:

```
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ON_VISITOR_RECORDS_FETCHED:
      return state.merge({
        visitorRecords: fromJS(action.visitorRecords),
      });
    case ON_RETURN_APPROVED:
      return state.merge({
        approvedBookingId: action.approvedBookingId,
      });
    case ON_VISITOR_RECORD_UPDATED:
      console.log(JSON.stringify(state.get("visitorRecords")));
      // console.log('action.bookingBeingUpdated: ' + action.bookingBeingUpdated)
      // console.log('JSON.stringify(action.updatedTextFields)' + JSON.stringify(action.updatedTextFields))
      // console.log('updatedExpectedArrival: ' + action.updatedExpectedArrival)
      // console.log('updatedExpectedDeparture: ' + action.updatedExpectedDeparture)
      // console.log('updatedStatus: ' + action.updatedStatus)
      return state;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

From here, I want to use **action.bookingBeingUpdated**, then find the corresponding record in **visitorRecords** and update it with the new **action.updatedTextFields, action.updatedExpectedArrival, action.updatedExpectedDeparture, action.updatedStatus**

I was reading [this](https://hackernoon.com/redux-patterns-add-edit-remove-objects-in-an-array-6ee70cab2456) article but I don't quite understand how the update happens there. Plus, the structure of the container there is different.

**EDIT**: Type of the elements inside visitorRecords ins not an anonymous object but a Map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you will do using **immutablejs**

```
case ON_VISITOR_RECORD_UPDATED:
    const newRecordsCollection = visitorRecords.map(record => {
        if (record.get('id') === action.bookingBeingUpdated) {
            return record.merge({
                updatedTextFields: action.updatedTextFields, 
                updatedExpectedArrival: action.updatedExpectedArrival, 
                updatedExpectedDeparture: action.updatedExpectedDeparture,
                updatedStatus: action.updatedStatus
            });
        }
        return record;
    });

    return state.merge({
        visitorRecords: newRecordsCollection
    });
```

Comment: I think your suggestion is pretty close but still not working. I had to write state.merge like this: return state.merge({visitorRecords: fromJS(newRecordsCollection)}); because it does not compile. Except for that, it will never get inside the 'if' because the type of the elements is Map

Comment: Sorry, skipped that `fromJS` does a deep conversion. So updated the `if condition` and internals of it as well. Corrected the `state.merge` to reflect the merge on state itself rather than independent merge operation `merge(state, newState)` which I assumed while typing in a haste.

Comment: I will accept this as an answer, but please update your 'get's with: record.get('id') and state.get('visitorRecords') on line 2

Comment: Yes. 'id' is not a computed field here. Will update. Good team work!

Answer (score 1):

You would generally use `map` on your array of vistorRecords, and pass the id and fields to update in the action, so for example it would look like this:

```
case ON_VISITOR_RECORD_UPDATED:
     console.log(JSON.stringify(state.get("visitorRecords")));
     const updatedRecords = state.visitorRecords.map(record => {
         if (record.id === action.bookingBeingUpdated) {
             return new Map({
                 ...record,
                 expectedArrival: action.updatedExpectedArrival
                 // other fields...
             });
         }
         return record;
     });
return state.merge({
    state,
    fromJS({visitorRecords: updatedRecords})
});
```

Comment: What about ht 3rd line of your suggestion? Isn't it supposed to be state.visitorRecords or something? I tried it this way but it is not working. I get 'Cannot read property 'map' of undefined'

Comment: It goes into `updatedRecords` which replaces `visitorRecords` property in the returned state object. You can obviously in-line it, it's split out to make it a little easier to read.

Comment: Sorry, updated it. Should have been `state.visitorRecords`

Comment: Even updated, I think there's an issue with the re-assignment. After the new state returned, every second update fails because the type of the state container changes (from Map to object. as described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43716784/how-to-set-a-property-as-an-array-i-initial-state)

Comment: Hadn't noticed you're using immutable. Yes, it will need a `fromJS`

Comment: Yeah, me also. I think I almost made it, what is left is to return a Map instead of anonymous object on line 5 of your code. Any idea?

Comment: you can just do `new Map({// obect contents})`, i'll update. i'd really consider just using plain objects

Comment: On line 5 I get: TypeError: object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

Answer (score 0):

You can update your record something like this:

```
case ON_VISITOR_RECORD_UPDATED:
  return {
      ...state, 
      visitorRecords: state.visitorRecords.map(record => {
        if(record.id.toString===action.bookingBeingUpdated.toString()){
          return {
            ...record, 
            updatedExpectedArrival: action.updatedExpectedArrival, 
            updatedExpectedDeparture: action.updatedExpectedDeparture, 
            updatedStatus: action.updatedStatus
          }
        } else {
          return record
        }
      })
    }
```

Comment: I am getting an error with the .map function. 'Cannot read property 'map' of undefined' Maybe because 'fromJS' generates some weird content type.

Comment: I think I am facing this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43716784/how-to-set-a-property-as-an-array-i-initial-state

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to actually `map()` the existing state and return a new one that includes the updated item-values that you desire.

Let's say you dispatch an action and a payload that includes the id and new values you want to use:

```
dispatch({
   type: "ON_VISITOR_RECORD_UPDATED"
   payload: newRecordData
})
```

Now in your reducer:

```
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ON_VISITOR_RECORDS_FETCHED:
      return state.merge({
        visitorRecords: fromJS(action.visitorRecords),
      });
    case ON_RETURN_APPROVED:
      return state.merge({
        approvedBookingId: action.approvedBookingId,
      });
    case ON_VISITOR_RECORD_UPDATED:
      return {
      ...state,
      visitorRecords: state.visitorRecords.map((record) => {
          if(record.id == action.payload.id){
             return{
                ...record,
                ...action.payload
             }
          }
      })
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

This ensures that you have a completely new state-value for your reducer

Answer (score 0):

````
Please don't use state.merge you can use 
```return {
       ...state,
       visitorRecords: [...state.visitorRecords,action.visitorRecords]

}```
Please send Id from action after and compare this id in ON_VISITOR_RECORD_UPDATED type like
```visitorRecords: {
       ...state.visitorRecords,
       data: state.visitorRecords.data.map((items) => {
            if (items.id=== action.id) {
               return { ...items, name: "updated name" };
             }
              return items;
            })
     }```
````